# Reading information from a Portable Executable (.exe)

Tags: files-and-directories, parsing, interoperability

I want to extract information from executable files, such as the names and sizes of sections, symbols, etc. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) has a diagram showing [the layout of a PE](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg). See also [this diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corkami/pics/master/binary/pe101/pe101.png)

It seems *Mathematica* isn't able to decode portable executables out of the box:

```
exe = Import["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"];
(* cannot infer the format *)
```

But we can at least read the bytes:

```
Import["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", "Byte"]

(* or alternatively *)

BinaryReadList["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"]
```

... so I've tried loading the bytes in myself and decoding the PE byte-by-byte:

```
(* extract bytes at zero-indexed offsets *)
at[bytes_, i_] := bytes[[i + 1]]
at[bytes_, i_, j_] := bytes[[i + 1 ;; j + 1]]

(* convert little-endian bytes to uint *)
uint[bytes_] := FromDigits[Reverse@bytes, 16]

(* Create a null terminated string from some bytes *)
nulltermstr[bytes_] := FromCharacterCode[TakeWhile[bytes, # > 0 &]]

exe = OpenRead["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", BinaryFormat -> True];
bytes = BinaryReadList[exe];
Close[exe];

peHeaderOffset = uint@at[bytes, 60, 63];
peMagic = FromCharacterCode[at[bytes, peHeaderOffset, peHeaderOffset + 1]]
(* result: PE *)

optionalHeaderSize = uint[at[bytes, peHeaderOffset + 5*4, peHeaderOffset + 5*4 + 1]];
sectionsStartOffset = peHeaderOffset + 3*8 + optionalHeaderSize;
sectionSize = 5*8;
sectionNames = Table[
  nulltermstr[at[bytes, sectionsStartOffset + sectionSize*i, sectionsStartOffset + sectionSize*i + 7]]
  , {i, 0, 6}]
(* result: {".text",".rdata",".data",".pdata",".didat",".rsrc",".reloc"} *)
```

It's quite tedious extracting pointers and getting the offsets from the binary format. As you can see, there are 'magic numbers' in my code which is not ideal.

Is there a better, ideally more declarative way to specify the format so that *Mathematica* can parse these binary headers? Ideally I'd like to be able to declare the structure of the PE file in a way similar to this tool: http://kaitai.io which would make decoding all sorts of binary formats much simpler from within *Mathematica*.

Comment: `Import["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", "Byte"]` works for me. So does `BinaryReadList["C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"]`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thanks I will remove that part of the question since I was just using it wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a pure *Mathematica* solution, but I ended up calling Python and using the [`pefile`](https://pypi.org/project/pefile/) module:

```
{sections, sectionsEntropy, importedSymbols} =
  ExternalEvaluate["Python", {
     "import pefile",
     "pe = pefile.PE('C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe')", 
     "[x.Name.decode('ascii').rstrip('\\x00') for x in pe.sections]",
     "[x.get_entropy() for x in pe.sections]",
     "[[[x.dll.decode('utf-8'),[s.name.decode('utf-8'), s.address]] for s in x.imports if s.name] for x in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]"
  }][[3 ;;]];

BarChart[sectionsEntropy, ChartLabels -> sections, AxesLabel -> "Entropy"]

(* show the symbols imported from in msvcrt.dll. Here it's the 3rd dll import *)
Grid[Flatten /@ importedSymbols[[3, All, 2 ;;]]]
```

[image: executable sections entropy and symbols]